# How to reshow preview frame of video at end of playback with jquery plugin "tubeplayer"

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, youtube-api

After my youtube video ends, I'd like to get the video back to it's initial state. I don't like the black screen with links at the end and i'd also prefer to hid the control bar, which although set to autohide, fails to hide when the video has stopped.
Is this possible using the

```
onPlayerEnded: function(){}, // when the player returns a state of ended
```

and

```
onStop: function(){}, // after the player is stopped
```

?

Keep in mind this would be for the object version, not the iframe. Tumblr (typically) embeds youtube as flash, not iframe.

You can see and example here: http://syndex.me, which by the way is already doing a ton of things successfully with Tumblr's limiting scope for video, via the pretty darn nice tubeplayer plugin. Now if only i can prettify/minimalise the end of the video too!
Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using the YouTube JSAPI. Rather than waiting for the player to finish I'd have a timer to check when the player's time-head has reached the duration, thus the video is complete but it's before the player begins to shut down. Then you simply seek back to 0 and pause, like so:

```
var i   = setInterval( checkPlayer, 100 );

function checkPlayer()
{
    if ( player.getCurrentTime() >= player.getDuration() )
    {
        clearInterval( i );

        player.seekTo( 0 );

        player.pause();
    }
}
```

And here's some working code:

```
<div id="player"></div>
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
<script>
<!--
    var player;
    var int;

    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            videoId: 'u1zgFlCw8Aw',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
            int = setInterval(handleInterval, 100);
        }
    }

    function handleInterval() {
        if (player.getCurrentTime() >= player.getDuration()) {
            player.pauseVideo();

            player.seekTo(0);
        }
    }
-->
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed, I'll check this out when I get back to this part of the site build and let you know. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty approach would be setting an interval timer that is 5 seconds longer than the video and then run onPlayerEnded when the interval completes.  Initiate the interval with blur or focusOut, basically some mouse event that people would be likely to do.

```
$(".video").blur(function() {
  $("#something").delay(30500).queue(function() {
    // do something..
```

If you want full control then you can use YouTube's Javascript API with callbacks and events.
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#SubscribingEvents

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you'd need to rely on a time out rather than seeing what the video does. For example this will fail if the user were to pause the video.

Answer (score 0):

Ahmed had the right idea. You can replicate this in the tubeplayer plugin by using the 'onPlayerEnded' method by doing the following:

`onPlayerEnded: function(){

        jQuery("#your-tubeplayer")

        .tubeplayer("seek", 0)

        .tubeplayer("pause");

}`

It's worth noting that the onStop method is a 'trigger' interceptor. The onPlayer[X] methods are actually invoked by the player, whereas the other onX events are used for hooks when invoking tubeplayer to perform the desired operation.

W.r.t. hiding the control bar: are you using showControls: false? As far as I can tell you can only set whether or not you want to show controls during instantiation of the youtube player itself (and can't change it on the fly afterward).

I tested the above fix and it the control bar remains hidden when using showControls:false.

Comment: also, i'm noticing now that the autohide param hasn't been implemented fully. sorry for this. i'll fix this as soon as i can